# Npm install fails with "Invalid Version: 3.5.0pr2"

Tags: npm

I'm getting this error doing an npm install trying to build [p5.js](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/)

```
npm ERR! Invalid Version: 3.5.0pr2
```

I can't figure out where that version could be coming from though.   The `package.json` shows the package version as 1.7.0:

```
  "version": "1.7.0",
```

The last lines of the log seem like it was working on SemVer with yui I think?

```
1948 timing reifyNode:node_modules/brfs-babel/node_modules/@babel/types Completed in 228575ms
1949 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yui 4022ms (cache revalidated)
1950 timing metavuln:packument:yui Completed in 4051ms
1951 verbose stack TypeError: Invalid Version: 3.5.0pr2
1951 verbose stack     at new SemVer (/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/classes/semver.js:38:13)
1951 verbose stack     at compareBuild (/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/functions/compare-build.js:3:20)
1951 verbose stack     at /home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/functions/sort.js:2:51
1951 verbose stack     at Array.sort (<anonymous>)
1951 verbose stack     at Object.sort (/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver/functions/sort.js:2:36)
1951 verbose stack     at Advisory.[calculateRange] (/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/metavuln-calculator/lib/advisory.js:159:28)
1951 verbose stack     at Advisory.load (/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/metavuln-calculator/lib/advisory.js:148:28)
1951 verbose stack     at Calculator.[calculate] (/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/metavuln-calculator/lib/index.js:59:14)
1951 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 0)
1951 verbose stack     at async Map.[init] (/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/audit-report.js:192:7)
1952 verbose cwd /mnt/d/src/github/processing/p5v2.js
1953 verbose Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
1954 verbose argv "/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node" "/home/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/npm" "ci"
1955 verbose node v16.14.2
1956 verbose npm  v8.5.0
```

Looks like it is installing `yui`.  The only module in package.json with a 3.5 version is chai:

```
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
```

`npm-why` gives this:

```
p5v2.js > grunt-contrib-yuidoc > yuidocjs > yui@3.18.1
```

`package-lock.json` has a few more that are 3.5.x, chokidar and event-emitter.   I'm using `npm ci` to use the package-lock and I've tried just `npm i` and get the same error.

Looking at `node_modules/yui`, it's package.json specifies version 3.18.1.  I'm stumped.  I've tried clearning the npm cache.  I've removed node_modules and tried several things.  I've even tried different versions of node using wsl and nvm.   I can't understand where 3.5.0pr2 could be coming from.